# Not able to get Publish Start Date metadata using REST call from SharePoint Site Pages library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, error, modern-experience, sitepages

I am trying to get the News Post metadata using REST call. I am getting all the fields value but not Publish Start Date. This field is being added when I have turned scheduled option for the library. Could you please help me why I am not getting the field value, it is giving error like:

> "The field or property "_PublishStartDate" does not exist. I am using below Odata query.

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/items/?$select=Title,_PublishStartDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to fetch the Publish Start Date using `OData__PublishStartDate`.

Try using below, it should work for you:

```
/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/Items?$select=Title,OData__PublishStartDate
```

**Output**:

Sample XML response received when I called above endpoint directly in browser tab:

```
<content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
        <d:Title>TestModernPage</d:Title>
        <d:OData__PublishStartDate m:type="Edm.DateTime">2021-09-24T02:00:00Z</d:OData__PublishStartDate>
    </m:properties>
</content>
```